# Facebook connectivity with Application

Tags: android, facebook

Regards, I want to make an android application which can simply update the Post. But its hard to find any tutorial for it. So if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the officail Facebook sdk for android.
Take a look at this tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I think this tutorial will help you:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Yes,I am already on this website now. But i thought may be if anyone knows some other way.